# Problem Formatting Page XX of XX in Word Footer Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm building my footers via code. I'm having an issue properly formatting the page counts in my Word footer when adding the fields via VBA. When the code runs the formatting always ends up as XXof XX (1of 20) instead of XX of XX (1 of 20). I have tried the following but the numbers always show the page number without a space before the word "of".

```
    With rng
        .Text = "NUMPAGES "
        Set oFooterRng1 = rng.Words(1)
        .Fields.Add Range:=oFooterRng1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    End With
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    rng.Text = " of "
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    With rng
        .Text = "PAGE "
        Set oFooterRng1 = rng.Words(1)
        .Fields.Add Range:=oFooterRng1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    End With
```

or this

```
    With rng
        .Text = "PAGE of NUMPAGES "
        Set oFooterRng1 = rng.Words(1)
        Set oFooterRng2 = rng.Words(3)
        .Fields.Add Range:=oFooterRng1, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
        .Fields.Add Range:=oFooterRng2, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES  \* Arabic ", PreserveFormatting:=True
    End With
```

Comment: Might be worth trying adding the space character in to the string? e.g. `rng.Text = Chr(32) & "of "`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  .InsertAfter Text:="Page "
  .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
  .InsertAfter Text:=" of "
  .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

And, to do it in reverse as you're trying to achieve:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="NUMPAGES", PreserveFormatting:=False
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .Text = " of "
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .Fields.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="PAGE", PreserveFormatting:=False
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  .Text = "Page "
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The footer is built in reverse, which is why I use the rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart syntax. I've tried what you suggested and it builds it as Page of201. I've tried reverse building it as well.

Comment: It doesn't do that when you use the code I posted - as I posted it. Why are you building the footer in reverse? In any event, I've added code for that.

Comment: Thanks. that works great. I think my issue was setting the range to the word instead of using Characters.Last. Thanks!!!